# on click event inside pageinit only works after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there're a lot of duplicate questions out there, I checked almost all of them, but I just couldn't find a solution in my case. So, here's my problem:

I have a banner which will show on every page of the project, inside the banner there's a close button to close the banner, and a download button which leads user to the app store to download the app. My banner works perfect only except I have to refresh the page to get these two buttons works. Here's my code:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
    $("#close").on("click", CloseBanner);
    $("#download").on("click", SetAppStorePath);
    //alert("pageinit");
});

function SetAppStorePath() {
    if (isIOS) {
        window.location = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myapp/id.....";
}
    else if (isAndroid) {
    window.location = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=.....";
    }
}

function CloseBanner() {
    $('.banner').hide();
}
```

Here's the simplified html:

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <a id="close">&times;</a>
        <a id="download">Download</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I did a little test, and found something tricky: I added that alert inside pageinit, I noticed that the alert is always executed(means my button on click events are always registered) when I jump from page A to page B. But when the button works, I see page A is gone, blank page shows, alert shows, then page B shows, the buttons work. When it doesn't work, the order is different, I still can see page A, then I see alert(I still can see page A now), then it changes to page B, the buttons don't work.

So seems that when pageinit executed after page jumped, it works,but sometimes pageinit executed before page jumped, then it doesn't work.

Comment: So I tried the accepted answer yesterday, it works fine in chrome virtual device. But today when I tested it on real device, the buttons totally don't work. Hope somebody can point out what's wrong here. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move following outside of the init and change it like following

```
$(document).on("click","#close", CloseBanner);
$(document).on("click","#download", SetAppStorePath);
```

when page init executes, DOM is not ready. that is the reason it is not binding to close or download elements. and this is the way to overcome that. you dont need pageinit event here

Comment: @YabinSong: Way of thanking here is, accepting and upvote :)

Comment: Hi @Chamika Sandamal, yesterday I tried this solution and it was working when I tested it in chrome. Today I tested it on real device, it doesn't work. I mean the buttons totally don't work. The weird thing is it's working on chrome virtual device... And when I use my old code above, the real device works. Do you know what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think your elements are dynamically created.  You may need event delegation.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $("body").on("click", "#close", CloseBanner);
    $("body").on("click", "#download", SetAppStorePath);
});
```

Comment: I tried this yesterday, it doesn't work. Also I remember it is suggested to use on pageinit rather than document ready for jQuery mobile?

Comment: I think your elements are dynamically created.  You may need event delegation. See the updated answer. @YabinSong

Comment: I guess my elements are not dynamically created.. anyway, I just tried the other answer and it works so I just accepted it. I will try yours later, thank you anyway. :)

Comment: Hi I tried your solution today, I got the same issue, it doesn't work on real device. The buttons don't work. Do you have any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: I don't know why it is not working. You can try `pagecreate` instead of `pageinit`. See updated answer. @YabinSong

Comment: hi, I tried your code inside `pageinit`, somehow it seems working now. I need to test more to make sure though. If it works fine, I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But I see a little issue here, I'm using iphone to test, when I click download, it shows the popup that asking do you wanna open app store, I can't choose, it will take me to app store immediately. then when I go back to my app, I see the popup for like 0.2 second, it disappear by itself. I don't want user see this popup. With my old code, I never saw this popup before. Do you know why now the popup shows?

Comment: I haven't iPhone. So I can't check the problem. But it should not be occurred. @YabinSong

Comment: I found out why it doesn't work on real device. It's not about `pageinit`. I fixed it by adding `href="#"` to my <a>. Thanks a lot for trying to help.