# Javascript works on emulator but doesn't work on real device

Tags: javascript, jquery

The background is related to this question I posted yesterday:

[on click event inside pageinit only works after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708833/on-click-event-inside-pageinit-only-works-after-page-refresh).

I got an answer for this question and I tried it in chrome devtools, it was working fine. But today when I tested it on real device(iPhone), it doesn't work. When I use my old code, the buttons work but only after refreshing. And when I use that accepted answer, the buttons don't work anymore. But it works in chrome virtual device perfectly. Hope somebody can help.

Comment: Have you tried placing your initialization code inside of a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` block?

Comment: It was recommended to put it inside `$(document).on("pageinit", function() {...});` My init code is to decide whether to show this banner or not, and it's inside this `pageinit` function(I didn't post this part of code in the question), and it works fine.

Comment: Yeah, his advice was probably wrong, assuming you followed it to the letter.  You should probably have just changed `$(document).on("pageinit", function` to `$(function`

Comment: @dtanders could you post an answer below? I didn't change my `pageinit` part. I just used his two on click events outside my `pageinit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
$(function () { //implicit DOMReady handler in jQuery
    $("#close").on("touchstart click", CloseBanner); //make sure you handle touch events
    $("#download").on("touchstart click", SetAppStorePath);
});
```

And just not bother with pageinit.  Edit:  Oh I see what the problem is!  You can't leave out the href on an anchor.  Add `href="#"` to those anchors and it should work fine.  Also consider changing the href on the app store link instead of setting window location because people like to see where links are going to take them.

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <a id="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <a id="download" href="#">Download</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And

```
$('#close').attr('href', 'app store URL goes here');
```

Comment: set the url seems not related to my question through.... I tried your code and added `href="#"`, but only works after page refresh... I wonder how to fix this...

Comment: hi, so I kept using the answer from the linking question, and I added `href="#"`, magic happens. It fixed my refresh issue, and it works on real device now. So I'm going to accept your answer since you're the one who mentioned `href="#"`. Thanks.

Comment: @YabinSong setting the URL is unrelated, but it is also an improvement to the user experience, especially if you care about accessibility issues

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna use a touch event for mobile devices like this:

```
$("#close").on("touchstart", CloseBanner);
```

Or if you don't want to use to sepearate events for different platforms then you can use a non-jquery option like this:

```
closeButton = document.getElementById('close');
closeButton.onclick = CloseBanner;
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I use the second code you suggested, since my app is designed for both ios and android. I put the code inside `pageinit`. It also only works after page refresh.

Comment: have u tried it outside the `pageinit` cause I was following the answer to ur original question.

Comment: I tried it outside `pageinit`. It makes the button doesn't work anymore.